Writing importer, can't tie bones to either actions (no animation_data) or NLA track
I need help with blender python import connecting vertex groups (bones) to animation.  Instead of animating the bones, 3d crosses are being animated (from the channels in my timeline).  My vertex groups are showing up under the mesh (apparently correctly).  I think I need constraints or modifiers, but I'm not sure what to do in python.


Here's my NLA and action code for import:
# Assign anim curves
node = defDict[key]
bone = None
if skeleton:
    if skeleton and key in skeleton.data.bones:
        bone = skeleton.data.bones[key]
    if node.blendData is None:  # Add an object if we need one for animation
        node.blendData = node.blendObject = bpy.data.objects.new(key, None)  # need to assign a bone somehow
    if bone:
        node.blendData.location = bone.head
    bpycollection.objects.link(node.blendObject)
    node.blendObject.select_set(True)
    if bone:
        node.blendData.location = bone.head

if not node.blendData.animation_data:
    node.blendData.animation_data_create()

node.blendData.animation_data.action = action
track = node.blendData.animation_data.nla_tracks.new()
track.name = "NLATRACK"
# track.strips.new(name=key, action=node.blendData.animation_data.action)
# track.strips.new(type='META_STRIP', frame_start=0, frame_end=100, meta_strip_elem=node.blendData.animation_data.action)
track.strips.new(name=action.name, start=0, action=action)

I am basing this off of the X3D/WRL importer, but I am adding armatures to the mix.  Hence my difficulty.
